# upload_to property in imageField can not save image on disk

Tags: django, save, modelform, imagefield

I'm a beginner in django. I want to have an imageField im my ModelForm can save image uploaded to upload_to path in my disk, but when i go through admin site i see that image is saved in a url not the directory on my disk.

```
user_image = models.ImageField( upload_to= '/images/', null=True , blank=True )
```

setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:\...\static'
```

when i click on image link in admin site it will go to a url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/time_save/userprofile/6/16.png/
```

I searched a lot in questions, but i didn't find a clear solution.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
UPLOAD_ROOT = 'C:\...\static'

upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_ROOT, base_url='/uploads')

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images', storage=upload_storage)
```

PS: You can define the UPLOAD_ROOT in your settings file.

Also do read through setting up your own [custom storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/)

Answer (score -1):

update `urls.py`

`from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(....),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`